# Proving using definition that $f=(f_1,f_2,...,f_m)$ is differentiable at $c$ iff $f_i$'s are differentiable at $c$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

I want to prove the following statement:
Suppose that $S$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb R^n$. Suppose that $f:S\to \mathbb R^m$ is differentiable at an interior point $c$ of $S$. Suppose that $f=(f_1,...,f_m)$, where $f_i:S\to \mathbb R$ for every $i\in \{1,2,...,m\}$. Then $f$ is differentiable at $c\in S$ if and only if $f_i$ is differentiable at $c$ for every $i\in \{1,2,...,m\}$.

Definition of differentiability: $f$ is said to be differentiable at an interior point $c$ of $S$ if there exists $h>0$ and a linear transformation $T_c:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$ such that for all $||v||<h$ the following holds:

$f(c+v)-f(c)=T_c(v)+o(||v||), v\to 0$. $T_c$ is also denoted by $f'(c)$.

I tried to prove it as follows:

($\Leftarrow$) Suppose that $f_i$'are differentiable at $c$.

It follows that
\begin{align*}
f_i(c+v)-f_i(c)-f_i'(c)v=o(||v||)
&\implies f_i(c+v)-f_i(c)-\nabla f_i(c).v=o(||v||)\\&\implies \sum_{i=1}^m\{f_i(c+v)-f_i(c)-\nabla f_i(c).v\}e_i=\sum e_i o(||v||)\\&\implies f(c+v)-f(c)-(\nabla f_1 (c).v, \nabla f_2(c).v,\cdots, \nabla f_m(c).v)=\color{red}{\sum e_i o(||v||)=o(||v||}\\&\color{blue}{\implies }f'(c) \text{ exists.}
\end{align*}
The red part is due to the fact that: $\frac{\sum o(||v||)}{||v||}=(\sum e_i)o(1)\to 0$ as $v\to 0$.
The implication highlighted in blue is true because $(\nabla f_1 (c).v, \nabla f_2(c).v,\cdots, \nabla f_m(c).v)=\color{green}{\begin {pmatrix} \nabla f_1 (c)\\\nabla f_2 (c)\\...\\ \nabla f_m (c)\end{pmatrix}}v$. The matrix in green is an $m\times n$ matrix and hence satisfies differentiability definition.

Now for the other direction:

($\Rightarrow$) Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $c$ so $\sum_{i=1}^m\{f_i(c+v)-f_i(c)-\color{purple}{\nabla f_i(c)}.v\}e_i=o(||v||)$.

For any $j\in \{1,2,...,m\}$, the following holds:

$|f_j(c+v)-f_j(c)-\nabla f_j(c).v|\leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m|f_i(c+v)-f_i(c)-\nabla f_i(c).v|^2}$.

It follows that:
$\frac{|f_j(c+v)-f_j(c)-\nabla f_j(c).v|}{||v||}\leq o(1)$. So taking $v\to 0$, it follows that $f_j(c+v)-f_j(c)-\nabla f_j(c).v=o(||v||)$.

It follows by definition of differentiablity that $f_j$ is differentiable for every $j\in \{1,2,...,n\}$.

Is my proof correct? Thanks.